# Why are the indexing methods missing when working on a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

My code is an update of an existing script which outputs an xslx file with a lot of data. The original script is pretty stable and has worked for ages.

What I'm trying to do is that, after the original script has ended and the xslx is created, I want to input the file into Pandas and then run a series of analyses on it, using the methods .loc(), .iloc(), .index().

But after I read the file into a variable, when I hit '.' after the variable's name in PyCharm, I get all the dataframe and NDArray methods... except those three that I need.

No errors, no explanations. They are just not there.

And if I ignore this and go on and type them up manually, the variable I put the results into doesn't show ANY methods when I hit '.' for it, next (instead of showing the methods for, say, a series).

I've tried clearing the xslx file of all formatting (it originally had empty lines hidden). I tried running .info() and .head() to make sure they both run fine (They seem to, yes). I even updated my code from Python 2.7 to Python 3.7 using the 2to3 scripts to see if that might change anything. It didn't.

```
import pandas as pd

analysis_file = pd.read_excel("F:\\myprogram\\output1.xlsx", "Sheet1")
analysis_file. <--- The problem's here
```

Really not sure how to proceed, and no one I've asked so far has been able to help me.

Comment: can you put a breakpoint, go into the breakpoint console, and type `type(analysis_file)`?

Comment: and if `info` and `head` are working (and you say they are), try `analysis_file.columns`

Comment: It returns: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Comment: There's no .columns() either, apparently.

Comment: As to .head() working, perhaps I spoke too soon. .head() only displays in console if I wrap it in print(), and then, it shows the first column and the last column and lists "..." in between.

Comment: That seems to be a [quirk of pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39905931/dataframe-head-not-shown-in-pycharm). As for your main problem, have a look at [this thread](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000142284-PyChram-autocomplete-for-import-library)

Comment: also (sorry about all the questions), what is the `type` of the results variable? can you use `loc`, `index` etc. successfully, just without Pycharm code completion?

Comment: This sounds like an issue with pycharm/intellisense. Your program seems to be working fine.

Comment: Agreed. Plowed through an ignored the autocomplete and it's working fine. Less pleasant, but fine. Thank you very much, everyone.